# select data from two rows as single row sequentially

Tags: mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maxid.png)As shown in the image below, we have 6 records for same vehicle_id (3 IN,3 OUT on different dates).
I need result as :

```
ID vehicle_id        IN               OUT
 1    X         first_record        second_record
 2    x         third_record        fourth_record
 3    x         fifth_record        sixth_record
```

So,for one record one IN time and one OUT time.

Is it possible to get with select query or do I need to write a stored proc?

Comment: 'Is it possible to get with select query' - probably , what version of mysql are you on and can you provide the table definition please.

Comment: Server version: 5.6.40,

Comment: CREATE TABLE tp_pass_approval (
  pass_master_id ,
  vehicle_id ,
  driver_id ,
  driver_license ,
  date_of_entry,
  date_of_exit ,
  updated_date ,
  updated_by ,
  created_date ,
  logout ,
  created_by ,
  status ,
  trip_status enum('IN','OUT','','') NOT NULL,
  process enum('IN_COMPLETE','COMPLETED','','')

Answer (score 0):

You could use sub queries with a limit clause for example

```
drop table if exists t;

create table t(id int auto_increment primary key, vid int, trip_status varchar(3),dt datetime);

insert into t (vid,trip_status,dt)
values
(1,'in','2018-12-01 01:00:00'),
(1,'out','2018-12-01 02:00:00'),
(1,'in','2018-12-01 03:00:00'),
(1,'out','2018-12-01 04:00:00'),
(1,'in','2018-12-01 05:00:00'),
(1,'in','2018-12-01 05:00:00');

select t.* 
        , (select case when t1.trip_status ='out' then trip_status
                    else concat(t1.trip_status, '**Error**')
                    end
                from t t1 where t1.vid = t.vid and t1.id > t.id  order by t1.id limit 1) nexttrip_status
        , (select t1.dt from t t1 where t1.vid = t.vid and t1.id > t.id  order by t1.id limit 1) next_dt
from t where trip_status = 'in';

+----+------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| id | vid  | trip_status | dt                  | nexttrip_status | next_dt             |
+----+------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
|  1 |    1 | in          | 2018-12-01 01:00:00 | out             | 2018-12-01 02:00:00 |
|  3 |    1 | in          | 2018-12-01 03:00:00 | out             | 2018-12-01 04:00:00 |
|  5 |    1 | in          | 2018-12-01 05:00:00 | in**Error**     | 2018-12-01 05:00:00 |
|  6 |    1 | in          | 2018-12-01 05:00:00 | NULL            | NULL                |
+----+------+-------------+---------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPbRJ.png) This image show the sql records as per your questions

This is the output as you expect. 
SQL = "Select x.id, x.vehicle_id, x.time as in_time, (Select  y.time from xx.new_table as y where y.id =x.id+1) as outtime from xx.new_table as x where x.id % 2 = 1" 
Please note "where x.id % 2 = 1" this condition you have to make it dynamic. Sometimes you have to set = 0 or = 1 based on your ID of the record. For that, you need to write addition select SQL to check it. Hope this will help you.

[Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3QHZ.png) To See output screen shot